# Relación one-to-many en Hibernate hbm con constraint check opcional

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, java-ee

Tengo una relación uno a muchos de un cheque con un catalogo de bancos. 
Identifico a un cheque por su `numero de cheque` y su `banco`. 
Si el cheque viene de un reemplazo de cheque, guardo `numerochequeanterior` y `catbancoanterior`. Este es el mapeo del Catalogo de bancos:

```
<class name="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Catbanco" table="catbanco">
        <id name="idbanco" type="int"  >
            <column name="idbanco" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <!--otras propiedades-->
        <set name="cheques" table="cheque" inverse="true" lazy="true"   fetch="select" >
            <key on-delete="noaction">
                <column name="idbanco" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Cheque" />
        </set>
        <set name="chequesanteriores" table="cheque" inverse="true" lazy="true" >
            <key>
                <column name="idbanco" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Cheque" />
        </set>
</class>
```

Y aquí esta la clase:

```
public class Catbanco implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int idbanco;
    //otras propiedades
    private Set<Cheque> cheques=new HashSet<Cheque>(0);
    private Set<Cheque> chequesanteriores=new HashSet<Cheque>(0);
    //Constructores y otros setter y getters
    public Set<Cheque> getCheques() {
        return cheques;
    }
    public void setCheques(Set<Cheque> cheque) {
        this.cheques = cheque;
    }
    public void addCheque(Cheque cheque) {
        this.cheques.add(cheque);
    }
    public Set<Cheque> getChequesanteriores() {
        return chequesanteriores;
    }
    public void setChequesanteriores(Set<Cheque> chequesanteriores) {
        this.chequesanteriores = chequesanteriores;
    }
}
```

Por otra parte este es el mapeo de cheque:

```
<class name="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Cheque" table="cheque">
        <id name="idcheque" type="long">
            <column name="idcheque" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="catbanco" class="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Catbanco"  fetch="join" >
            <column name="idbanco" unique-key="banconumerocheque" index="idxcatbanco" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="numerocheque" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="numerocheque" length="7" unique-key="banconumerocheque" index="idxnumerocheque" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="catbancoanterior" class="conciliacion.dao.modelosBO.Catbanco" fetch="join" >
            <column name="idbancoanterior"  />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="numerochequeanterior" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="numerochequeanterior" length="7" />
        </property>
       <!--Otras propiedades-->
</class>
```

Y las clase de cheques:

```
public class Cheque implements Serializable {
    private Long idcheque;
    private Catbanco catbanco;
    private Integer numerocheque;
    private Catbanco catbancoanterior;
    private Integer numerochequeanterior;
    //otras propiedades, constructores, setters y getters
    public Long getIdcheque() {
        return idcheque;
    }
    public void setIdcheque(Long idcheque) {
        this.idcheque = idcheque;
    }
    public Catbanco getCatbanco() {
        return catbanco;
    }
    public void setCatbanco(Catbanco catbanco) {
        this.catbanco = catbanco;
    }
    public Integer getNumerocheque() {
        return numerocheque;
    }
    public void setNumerocheque(Integer numerocheque) {
        this.numerocheque = numerocheque;
    }
     public Catbanco getCatbancoanterior() {
        return catbancoanterior;
    }
    public void setCatbancoanterior(Catbanco catbancoanterior) {
        this.catbancoanterior = catbancoanterior;
    }
    public Integer getNumerochequeanterior() {
        return numerochequeanterior;
    }
    public void setNumerochequeanterior(Integer numerochequeanterior) {
        this.numerochequeanterior = numerochequeanterior;
    }
}
```

Todo esto funciona bien, pero el problema es que me han dicho que el cheque anterior puede venir de un deposito. El deposito trae un numero y no trae banco. 
Ese numero me han pedido guardarlo en `numerochequeanterior` y el archivo que me proporcionan trae un `00` en el lugar del banco (Porque no es un cheque). Actualmente mi configuración generaba un `check constraint` de sql server asi:

```
ALTER TABLE [cheques].[cheque]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_7y1jlqn1xx09ukmstalvhl09s] FOREIGN KEY([idbancoanterior])
    REFERENCES [cheques].[catbanco] ([idbanco])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [cheques].[cheque] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_7y1jlqn1xx09ukmstalvhl09s]
```

Mi pregunta es **¿Hay alguna forma para que desde hibernate pueda generar esta configuración, pero que el CHECK sea opcional?** Esta configuración obliga a que cada valor de `idbancoanterior` que guarde en cheque, tiene que existir en `catbanco`. Pero ahora me gustaría insertar ese `00` ahí, que es un valor que no existe en `catbanco`. Todo esto es buscando no dejar `null` en `idbancoanterior`.